# Call Usercontrol method from another form

Tags: vb.net

I want to call method from `Usercontrol` in `form` the method(showlistbox) is to fill the products in listbox, when the user update or delete a product I want to call the method so it will update the listbox that contains the product in the `usercontrol`.

I have 2 forms main form that have 'usercontrol' the 'usercontrol' have listbox and other controls, I'm using method called 'showlistbox' display the products in the listbox, if the user double click on any product in listbox this will open new form contains the product details, so if the user delete or update the product i want the listbox in the 'usercontrol' also update or refresh by calling the ' showlistbox' method.

i tried this but it show me this error : `the connectionstring property has not been initialized`

this is the code:

```
dim m_product as new products
m_product.showlistbox()
```

And this is the `showlistbox` method:

```
Public Sub showlistbox()
    Try
        'فحص الاتصال بقاعدة البيانات
        If SQL.conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            SQL.conn.Close()
        End If
        SQL.conn.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select pname from products where not esection= N'archive' order by date DESC", SQL.conn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim myRow As DataRow
        For Each myRow In dt.Rows
            ListBox1.Items.Add(myRow.Item(0)).ToString()
        Next
        SQL.conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

but its not working, how can i done it?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to connect to a database and you never initialized the connection string. The code you show doesn't contain the part causing the error. What is `showlistbox`?

Comment: The showlistbox is the method that fill products in listbox, I'm using select statement and its work fine when i use it in the same 'user ontrol ' , all what i want to call the method in another form thats it.

Comment: I meant if that is a method you wrote, you should probably post the code for that too.

Comment: @whrrgarbl I updated the question take a look.

Answer (score 0):

From the information and sound of it you're attempting to call a private member on form 1 from form 2.  Try creating a public sub on form 1 to call which contains a variable equal to the object you need.

```
Public Sub frm1LstBox()
Dim lstbx as liistbox = m_product
End Sub
```

Comment: Its a public method not private, but I'm calling it from 'usercontrol'

Comment: Ok, so there is a control on form 2 that should update a listbox on form 1?  If form 1 load event hasn't been initialized, you'd want to create a new instance of it to make the changes and then load the new object.

Comment: I have 2 forms main form that have 'usercontrol' the 'usercontrol' have listbox and other controls, I'm using method called 'showlistbox' display the products in the listbox, if the user double click on any product in listbox this will open new form contains the product details, so if the user delete or update the product i want the listbox in the 'usercontrol' also update or refresh by calling the ' showlistbox' .

Comment: Is it a data source, dictionary, list(of string), class objects to populate the product listbox?